# Web Development Stack map?

Tags: web, frameworks, libraries

As a programmer, one day you think you advance in understanding the next you are stupid again, and this goes forever.

and i like it don't get me wrong.

Making my first steps into web development this schema continues but it gets frantic. Its not only reading about MVC,MVVM, SPA etc

Web development still feels very loose in terms of "rules established" so you have many options especially in client side operations.

AngularJS,Breeze,upshot,knockout,jquery,bootstrap and the list goes on and on.

I tried to find an illustration,a table, something that shows the current state of web development stack of "entities" available that a web developer should be aware of...

is there any?

Comment: At least for every "layer" or "part of a web application there should be a ma of available approaches/tools.....I am surprised that there isn't, probably this would be the task of some of the "big" boys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice partial answer is this site:

[TODOMVC](http://todomvc.com/)

Shows a simple to-do application that has been implemented with various technologies.

You can download the sources and check it out yourself.